# Java only Operating System

Tags: java, operating-system

Are there any operating systems that when fully loaded only provide a java environment for console application execution? Ideally one which will automatically start programs when its loaded up

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but maybe Android?

Comment: You can start with linux and remove anything you don't need (just like Android)

Comment: put all your java stuffs in a folder,make a user account having permission only on that folder and then disable XServer in linux....bingo :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a such thing with name: [JavaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS)

From my point of view better approach is to install a Linux distribution pack or small Linux distribution pack with java support and put your java code to the OS startup. To run it when OS has been started.

Comment: Both of those sound good. Are there any linux distros i should consider (sorry, lifetime windowser)?

Comment: Consider [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/overview) or [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/). Both are good, but I would select Ubuntu Server. Also check this website: http://distrowatch.com/

Comment: If you need a linux distro with small footprint, for instance when you have not powerful hardware, then google for `small linux distro`. There are many small linux distributions which do not require much resources and work with java.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it did exist, it would not by itself provide any security benefits.

A java application can still exercise almost all user-ring authority made available by the OS.  If it can write somewhere on the library load path or start another java application with a specified library load path then it can:

1. Write out a native library to the file-system.
2. Define a class with `native` methods backed by that library.
3. Call `System.loadLibrary` to load that library.
4. Invoke those `native` method to execute arbitrary user-ring code.

If you want an operating system that allows you to effectively control the authority available via the shell, then read up on

1. "secure operating systems" like [KeyKOS](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~KeyKOS/),
2. sandboxing processes using "virtual machines", and
3. providing a smaller shell interface using "restricted shells".

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [Phantom OS](http://www.dz.ru/en/solutions/phantom/), being worked on by some Russian programmers. The system has no concept of files. Everything is an object living in one large memory space.